# Quake 1 Darkplaces Engine Save and Config Path

Tags: backup, engine

I recently installed and played Quake 1 but I would like to know where darkplaces saves the config and save files for backing up my data. Im installed the darkplaces engine through the command line: "apt-get install darkplaces"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are in ~/.darkplaces so if you back up your home folder you are good.